# How can I get css blending modes to apply to different "layers"

Tags: css

I've got a blueprint that I want to absolutely position divs on top of in order highlight certain rooms.

Using the alpha channel (rgba), I can still see the blueprint's "ink" underneath, but depending on the color saturation the drawing gets obscured.

I know that I can use `background-blend-mode: multiply` on the div that contains the blueprint in order to get the desired effect, but it applies it to the entire image because I have to specify the color and the image on the same div. This is hard to explain but easy to show, so I mocked it up with paint.net here:

[image]

Again, I can get the desired look using `background-blend-mode` but would apply it to the entire background image. I want the color from a div to `multiply` everything that is underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I started off writing this question and found out that it is a browser support issue. I eventually found `mix-blend-mode` which is what will apply blending modes to everything "underneath" a div/element, unfortunately, Chrome (as of today) doesn't support it. Firefox, however, does. It is possible to turn it on in chrome going to chrome://flags/ and enable "experimental Web Platform features".

I found the following link pretty helpful in general, I just didn't realize that they talk about both background-blend-mode and mix-blend-mode. http://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Here is a screenshot of it working in firefox:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use background-blend-mode, and play with the background-image properties.

Not a very nice solution, but can get you going before waiting from Chrome next release

```css
.test {
   width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightgreen, lightgreen), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfAyW.png);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size: 100px 140px, cover;
  background-position: 10px 40px, 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```